# Making a bootstrapjs button to behave as dropdown

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a bootstrapjs button to behave as a bootstrap dropdown

The bootstrap documentation only gives a dropdown as a list item:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

I tried to give it the class `btn` but no luck, it looked messed up and was not working properly

Comment: Read here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns

Comment: How did I missed this?! Thank you!